# merging very large (thousands) very small files

Tags: r, json

I need to merge several batches of very large number of small size files (collected tweets for my project for each user). The large number is approx 50,000 files :(

I don't have a particular issue with the code, but my R just get "frozen" in the merge even if i keep files at 10 000 number. Any ideas?

The code i use is:

```
files <-   list.files(
     path = file.path(path),
     pattern = pattern,
     recursive = TRUE,
     include.dirs = TRUE,
     full.names = TRUE   )

json.data_all <- data.frame()


for (i in seq_along(files)) {   
  filename <- files[[i]]  
  json.data <- jsonlite::read_json(filename, simplifyVector = TRUE)  
 json.data_all <- dplyr::bind_rows(json.data_all, json.data) 
 }
```

I have several of such folders.. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It is generally easier and faster to make a list of all of your data frames and then after the loop use `bind_rows` to merge the entire list in one go.
R does not handle memory very well so the constant binding inside the `for()` loop becomes very slow creating and deleting the ever growing data structure.

Something like this should work:

```
files <- list.files( path = file.path(path), pattern = pattern, recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE, full.names = TRUE )

json.data <- lapply(files, function(file){
   jsonlite::read_json(file, simplifyVector = TRUE)
})
json.data_all <- dplyr::bind_rows(json.data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't bind by rows or otherwise augment data in a `for` loop, it is very slow.
Try something like the following.

```
files <- list.files(path = file.path(path), pattern = pattern, recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

json.data_all <- lapply(files, jsonlite::read_json, simplifyVector = TRUE)
json.data_all <- data.table::rbindlist(json.data_all)
dim(json.data_all)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below should solve your problem, and also would be fast in execution due to threading

```
library("parallel")
library("foreach")
library("doParallel")

cluster1 = makeCluster(detectCores(logical=FALSE), type="PSOCK", outfile="")
registerDoParallel(cluster1)

files <-   list.files( path = file.path(path), pattern = pattern, recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE, full.names = TRUE )
dataList = foreach(file=files) %dopar% {
    jsonlite::read_json(file.path(path, file1), simplifyVector = TRUE) 
}
json.data_all = data.table::rbindlist(dataList)

stopCluster(cluster1)
```